# Is every bounded subset Lebesgue measurable and with finite measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Royden's 4e book on measure theory discusses that every bounded set in the space of real numbers has finite measure. I would like to please get some hints in proving the same.

Although, the above result can be easily proved for outer measure, the author doesn't seem to provide an intuition regarding this result for measure function.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Find some $[-R,R]$ containing your bounded measurable set $E$ and use monotonicity of measure. Do note there exist bounded but not Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AlejandroEpelde But here, the author says that $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \gamma} (\lambda + E)$ is measurable because it's bounded. ( where $\gamma$ is a infinite bounded set of real numbers). It's the union of these sets which is giving me the trouble. So, I want to prove that the infinite bounded union of measurable sets is measurable?

Comment: No, measurability follows from $E$ and its translates being Lebesgue-measurable and the fact  the Lebesgue-measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra. Then boundedness gives finite measure.

Comment: @AlejandroEpelde Got it. Thank you. If you would like to post an answer, I will accept it and close the question